# Adding React Template to React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying using react-template. I'm using grunt, browserify and react-templatify. The code is compliled without errors but nothing is displayed. The code is simple.

hello.rt.js code compiled with react-template

```
import React from 'react';
var helloRT = function () {
    return React.createElement('div', {}, 'Hola Rt');
};

export default helloRT;
```

Rtexample.js

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import helloRT from './hello.rt.js';



class Rtexample extends Component {
  
    render(){
      return helloRT;
   }
}



export default Rtexample;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a full function in `hello.rt.js` rather than an anonymous function fixed my problem. See:

```js
/* old */
var helloRT = function () { /* ... */ }

/* new */
function helloRT() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: If this is what worked for you, make sure to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Gruntfile.js like this:

```
reactTemplates: {
        dist: {
          src: ['./src/components/**/*.rt'], //glob patterns of files to be processed
          options: {
            modules: 'es6',  //possible values: (amd|commonjs|es6|typescript|none)
            format: 'stylish' //possible values: (stylish|json)
          }
        }
      },
```

es6 is important. This solved the problem. Compile rt file like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
export default function () {
    return React.createElement('div', {}, 'Hola Rt cambiada');
}
```